# Display dropdown sublevel (autonav Concrete5)

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, navigation, concrete5

I am trying to display a dropdown-menu on the 2nd-level in the Concrete5 auto-navigation template, but it does not seem to work.

- Nav-item
- **Dropdown menu** *(works)*

  - Nav-item
  - **Dropdown menu** *(does not work, closes first dropdown )*
- Nav-item

I use the following code:

```
    <?php defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die("Access Denied."); ?>
    <?php View::getInstance()->requireAsset('javascript', 'jquery');
    $navItems = $controller->getNavItems();
    foreach ($navItems as $ni) {
        $classes = array();

        if ($ni->isCurrent) {
            $classes[] = 'nav-selected'; }
        if ($ni->inPath) {
            $classes[] = 'nav-path-selected';}
        if ($ni->hasSubmenu) {
            $classes[] = 'dropdown-menu';}
    }

    echo '<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">';
    foreach ($navItems as $ni) {
        echo '<li class="' . $ni->classes . '">';
        if ($ni->isEnabled) {
            $ni->hasSubmenu;
        }
        if ($ni->hasSubmenu && $ni->level >= 2  ) {
            echo '<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle dropdown-lvl2" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">' . $ni->name . '<span class="caret"></span></a>';
            } elseif ($ni->hasSubmenu){
                echo '<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">' . $ni->name . '<span class="caret"></span></a>'; //opens a dropdown sub-menu        
        } else {
            echo '<a href="' . $ni->url . '" target="' . $ni->target . '" class="' . $ni->classes . '">' . $ni->name . '</a>';
        }
        if ($ni->hasSubmenu && $ni->level >= 2  ) {
            echo '<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lvl2">'; 
            } elseif ($ni->hasSubmenu){
                echo '<ul class="dropdown-menu">'; 
        } else {
            echo '</li>'; //closes a nav item
            echo str_repeat('</ul></li>', $ni->subDepth); 
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>'; //closes the top-level menu
```

So I think the problem is the Bootstrap `data-toggle` opening and closing the `dropdown-menu`. Any Idea how to make the dropdown work on the other levels.

Comment: 2. line: the jquery should already be added, therefor your `requireAsset()` is unnecessary. Or do you use an older c5 version?

Comment: I am using version 8.3.2. Deleting the line does not break or fix the issue. This is the generated HTML [link](https://jsfiddle.net/bpn2c3u7/1/) (simplified)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to display the multilevel dropdown-menu. I added the following JavaScript:

https://jsfiddle.net/fxv214z0/

```
<script>
  (function($){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault(); 
                event.stopPropagation(); 
                $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
                $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```